# Instagram API user verified property

Tags: instagram-api

Is is possible to return the verified flag from the Instagram User API?

The [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) makes no mention of it, so I'm wondering if it's a feature will be added or is currently undocumented

Comment: Same question (same ask time): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284465/instagram-api-can-i-check-if-user-is-verified   Answer here is to actually get contents of user's page and check pagesource via regex. Shame Insta doesn't include this in return from user endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the documentation is not complete. I mean that when you make a call, you can get more information than the ones you can see in the documentation (RESPONSE).
However, I read all the documentation looking for the verified flag too and I didn't find it. 
You need to get it without using the API.