# How to retrieve Instagram username if Verified or not?

Tags: python, api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there any Instagram API or No API, website, endpoint call that can gets me if the username stated verified or not?

I've tried:

```
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=nike
```

But it return with too much "is_verified": true

There's no easier way? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instagram API: Can i check if user is verified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284465/instagram-api-can-i-check-if-user-is-verified)

Comment: @micpap25 this not duplicate and its not working. Check yourself please.